# How to Inject Services in another Service using Factory to create them

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, factory, symfony4

I have a little problem with the creation of  my services in symfony 4.1

I use Factories to create my services, and to force the Factory to have the expected method I made an Interface

```
<?php

namespace App\Service\Factory\Interfaces;


use App\Service\Interfaces\BaseModelServiceInterface;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;

/**
 * Interface ModelServiceFactoryInterfaces
 * @package App\Service\Factory\Interfaces
 */
interface ModelServiceFactoryInterfaces
{

    /**
     * Create the Model related Service
     *
     * @return BaseModelServiceInterface
     */
    public function createService(DocumentManager $dm);

}
```

I get the DocumentManager from autowired services to create the Repository in the Factory and pass it to the service, like this

```
/**
 * Class ChapterServiceFactory
 * @package App\Service\Factory
 */
class ChapterServiceFactory implements ModelServiceFactoryInterfaces
{
    /**
     * @param DocumentManager $dm
     * @return ChapterService|BaseModelServiceInterface
     */
    public function createService(DocumentManager $dm)
    {
        $chapterRepository = $dm->getRepository(Chapter::class);
        /**
         * @var $chapterRepository ChapterRepository
         */
        return new ChapterService($chapterRepository);
    }

}
```

The problem with that is, if I want to have another service in my ChapterService I can't autowire it in the Factory because of the Interface, but I don't want to delete the Interface either.

Is there a way to have "dynamic arguments" with an Interface, or another way than the Interface to force the Factories to have the createService method ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no workaround for this: if you declare an interface as the argument, then you need to provide an explicit implementation for that interface. This means that you cannot declare two default implementations for the same interface. Only thing you can do in this case is to declare explicitly the service and all its arguments.

By the way, as you're writing about Doctrine Repositories, I suggest you to take a look at [`ServiceEntityRepository`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Repository/ServiceEntityRepository.php): extending this class from one of your repos will make automatically the report a service that you can inject where needed.

Comment: OK so I need to delete the interface if I want others services (or make another interface that redefine the method), right ?

I use Doctrine ODM and I didn't see any equivalence for the `ServiceEntityRepository`. the feature was started some months ago but there is no news about it.

Comment: @Etshy I would prefer to keep the interfaces (the same if it's same behavior) and declare explicitly the service tbh.

Comment: Okay so if I need another service in a service i make a specific interface for this one (cause most of my service will just have a repository). Thanks a lot.